# How to copy the customer entity's taxvat value to the customer address entity's vat id

Tags: magento2.4.0, taxvat, vat-id

How can I copy the value in customer entity's taxvat field to the same customer's customer address entity's VAT ID field? It has to take into account that customer can have many addresses, and I want the same taxvat to be copied to all of the addresses.

I guess there are several ways to do this. With MySQL, with export-import functionality and with code.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this with this SQL query:

```
UPDATE customer_address_entity,customer_entity SET customer_address_entity.vat_id = customer_entity.taxvat WHERE customer_address_entity.parent_id = customer_entity.entity_id;
```

It copied the taxvat to all of the addresses of customers'.